# Multiple domains for a single site in wordpress multisite

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I have a multisite network on an Amazon Lightsail server, and for one specific site, I need to set it such that exampledomain1.com leads to the English version of the site, and exapledomain2.fr leads to the French version of the site.

I have done this using polylang, and set these exact settings. But when I set an A record on both domains to the ip, only eyampledomain1.com works, which is the domain I set when creating the site.

The other domain, exampledomain2.fr takes me to https://exapledomain1.com/wp-signup.php?new=exapledomain2.fr

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: In domainconfig propably a 301-redirect from `exapledomain2.fr` to `https://exapledomain1.com/fr` could help you out?

Comment: Questions about server and network configuration/DNS are not programming questions. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this and ask on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ or, perhaps, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/